# Parsing User-Agents with Symfony 1.x

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, user-agent

I'm upgrading an old web application developed with Symfony 1.4.

I need to parse user agents in order to retrive information such as OS type (Windows, Android, iOS, Linux etc) , OS version, browser type (Chrome, IE, Android Browser..) and browser version.

For user-agents generated by mobile devices I use sfTeraWurflPlugin, who works fine.

I need something similar for parsing user-agents generated by desktop computers.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get_browser()](http://docs.php.net/get_browser) function, which is available in core php.

The most robust alternative solution I know about is a [ua-parser](https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser/tree/master/php) library. It is not a symfony bundle, but it is still easy to use. It has a huge user-base and is extensively tested. 2.x versions are compatible with php 5.2, 3.x versions are for php 5.3+

Comment: I know that function, but is not easy to use as sfTeraWurflPlugin.
For example, it returns [platform] => WinXP instead of [OS] => Windows, [OS_version] => XP.

Comment: well… symfony1 is quite a dead beast, and as you wrote: you're in process of upgrading this app, so there isn't much sense in spending time on a perfect solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change framework or framework version. Before  writing an big switch/case statement for parsing get_browser()' results, I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: I'm having issues trying to use Ua-Parser. I downloaded the master from git, I downloaded all the dependencies through Composer.

But when I run the app i get he following error: Fatal error: 
Cannot redeclare class Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser in {path to my app}\vendor\symfony\yaml\Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser.php on line 22